# How can I unpack a returned generic list of a custom type on the Compact Framework client?

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, compact-framework

I have a REST method on the Web API server that reads from a local-to-it MS Access table, and stores the values into a generic list, and passes that back:

```
public List<SiteMapping> GetSiteMappings(String userId, String pwd)
{
    List<SiteMapping> siteMappings = new List<SiteMapping>();
    string connStr =
        string.Format(
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID={0};Password={1};Data 
Source=C:\CDBWin\DATA\CDBSetup.MDB;Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\CDBWin\Data\sscs.mdw", userId, 
pwd); 
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT site_no, location_num FROM t_sites order by site_no";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            using (OleDbDataReader oleDbD8aReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (oleDbD8aReader != null && oleDbD8aReader.Read())
                {
                    int siteNum = oleDbD8aReader["SiteNumber"] is DBNull
                        ? 0
                        : Convert.ToInt16(oleDbD8aReader["SiteNumber"]);
                    string locationNum = oleDbD8aReader["location_num"] is DBNull
                        ? string.Empty
                        : oleDbD8aReader["location_num"].ToString();
                    siteMappings.Add(new SiteMapping { SiteNumber = siteNum, LocationNumber = 
locationNum });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return siteMappings;
}

public class SiteMapping
{
    public int SiteNumber { get; set; }
    public string LocationNumber { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
}
```

I call it from the client (Windows CE / Compact Framework) like so:

```
public ArrayList FetchSiteMappings(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpwreq = SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(url, HttpMethods.GET, String.Empty, "application/xml");
    // Idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350670/how-to-extract-zipped-file-received-from-httpwebresponse
    var response = httpwreq.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    responseStream. <= I'm stuck here
}
```

...but I don't know what to do with the response stream -- How do I convert what is passed back from a generic list to an ArrayList?

Here's the *SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials()* method, in case anybody's interested (or even if they're not):

```
public static HttpWebRequest SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(string uri, HttpMethods method, string data, string contentType)
{
    WebRequest request = null;
    try
    {
        request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpMethods), method).ToString();
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).Accept = contentType;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

        if (method != HttpMethods.GET && method != HttpMethods.DELETE)
        {
            byte[] arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            request.ContentLength = arrData.Length;
            using (Stream oS = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                oS.Write(arrData, 0, arrData.Length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            request.ContentLength = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = String.Format(
                "{0}; Inner Ex: {1}; Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, 
ex.StackTrace);
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From 
FileXferREST.SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(): {0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
    }
    return request as HttpWebRequest;
}
```

### UPDATE

I've changed the SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials() method to return a HttpWebResponse instead of a HttpWebRequest (see [Is there something missing from this (borrowed/adapted) code, or am I not seeing where a Get gets fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804430/is-there-something-missing-from-this-borrowed-adapted-code-or-am-i-not-seeing) for the (minimal) details in the Update there), so the FetchSiteMappings() method has also changed; it is now:

```
HttpWebResponse httpwresp = SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(url, HttpMethods.GET, String.Empty, "application/xml");
httpwresp. <= what now???
```

Comment: This kneejerk downvoting is actually becoming somewhat amusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this should work:

```
public ArrayList FetchSiteQuery(string url)
{
    List<String> ls = new List<string>();
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    string tempString = null;
    int count = 0;
    // Idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350670/how-to-extract-zipped-file-
received-from-httpwebresponse
    HttpWebResponse httpwresp = SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(url, HttpMethods.GET, 
String.Empty, "application/xml");
    var responseStream = httpwresp.GetResponseStream();
    // adapted the following from http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx
    do
    {
        // fill the buffer with data
        count = responseStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

        // make sure we read some data
        if (count != 0)
        {
            // translate from bytes to ASCII text
            tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

            // continue building the string
            ls.Add(tempString);
        }
    }
    while (count > 0); // any more data to read?
    ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
    myArrayList.AddRange(ls);
    return myArrayList;
}
```

### UPDATE

Yes, it did work; this test code:

```
private void button56_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList al = FetchSiteQuery("http://localhost:21608/api/sitequery/getall/dbill/ppus/3");
    foreach (String s in al)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```

...showed me this:

[image]

...and several more "pages" (message box instantiations) after that.

Comment: A suggestion: if you're using CF 3.5, get away from those untyped `ArrayList`s.  Return the generic `List<string>` you already have, or a typed array.