# Is there something missing from this (borrowed/adapted) code, or am I not seeing where a Get gets fired?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, http-method

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803761/how-can-i-unpack-a-returned-generic-list-of-a-custom-type-on-the-compact-framewo) that sends an HttpWebRequest, but on looking closer at my method SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(), which I'm sure I adapted from something I found on StackOverflow some time in the past, it seems as if something's missing. See if this looks fishy to you, when the Http method is Get:

```
public static HttpWebRequest SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(string uri, HttpMethods method, 
    string data, string contentType)
{
    WebRequest request = null;
    try
    {
        request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpMethods), method).ToString();
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).Accept = contentType;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

        if (method != HttpMethods.GET && method != HttpMethods.DELETE)
        {
            byte[] arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            request.ContentLength = arrData.Length;
            using (Stream oS = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                oS.Write(arrData, 0, arrData.Length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            request.ContentLength = 0;
        }
        //((HttpWebRequest)request). // <= should this call "GetRequestStream())" or 
"BeginGetResponse" or "GetResponse" or "RequestUri" or ... ???
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = String.Format(
                "{0}; Inner Ex: {1}; Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, 
ex.StackTrace);
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From 
FileXferREST.SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(): {0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
    }
    return request as HttpWebRequest;
}
```

Shouldn't there be an explicit "sending" of the HttpWebRequest even when the http type is "Get"? Do I need to add something at the commented out line above, or do I need to change this part:

```
if (method != HttpMethods.GET && method != HttpMethods.DELETE)
{
    byte[] arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    request.ContentLength = arrData.Length;
    using (Stream oS = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        oS.Write(arrData, 0, arrData.Length);
    }
}
else
{
    request.ContentLength = 0;
}
```

...to this:

```
byte[] arrData = null;
if (method != HttpMethods.GET && method != HttpMethods.DELETE)
{
    arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    request.ContentLength = arrData.Length;
}
else
{
    request.ContentLength = 0;
}
using (Stream oS = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    oS.Write(arrData, 0, arrData.Length);
}
```

...or else how is the REST method actually called when the http method == GET???

### UPDATE

Or should the refactoring really be something like this:

```
public static HttpWebResponse SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(string uri, HttpMethods method, 
    string data, string contentType)
{
    . . .
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    return response;
}
```

(IOW, change the return type from HttpWebRequest to HttpWebResponse, and append those two lines shown above to the end of the method)?

Comment: Impressive! It only took my "secret admirer" 42 seconds to downvote my post! I must be the most important person in his life for him to  be that dedicated. And I don't even know the cat (I don't think). It must be a cat; chicks aren't that obsessive.

Comment: The method is set in 'request.Method = Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpMethods), method).ToString();' line, so the code snippet looks ok. Call request.GetResponse() or request.BeginGetResponse() to perform the operation.

Comment: Okay, so my Update looks like the ticket to you?

Comment: Yes, looks fine. It was made while I was writing the comment so I didn't see it before posting the comment.

Comment: Make your first comment an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: I am wondering who bothered to downvote the question without leaving any explanation...

Comment: That happens to me "all the time"; somebody has taken a fancy to me, I think.

Comment: If he tracks me down and attacks me with his pocket protector, he will go down in geek lore as "The Stacker Stalker" (or simply, "The StackOverflow Stalker").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is set in `request.Method = Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpMethods), method).ToString();` line, so the code snippet looks ok. Call request.GetResponse() or request.BeginGetResponse() to perform the operation.